# Redux + React: avoid DOM comparison on small changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my component architecture (relevant component in bold):

- App

  - Attributes

    - **Evaluator**
    - Commander
    - StyleGrid
    - DataGrid

This is part of my merged reducers:

- Root

  - appState

    - **isImageFocused (boolean)**
  - ...

When **isImageFocused** changes, the color of the following image changes:

[image: Evaluator component]

The image is part of the Evaluator component. Everything works as expected, nevertheless, I've noticed the entire **Attributes**'s component-subtree gets re-evaluated (shadow DOM comparison, right?) for that small change. As far as I understand, this means **Attributes**, **Evaluator**, **StyleGrid** and **DataGrid** components are all re-evaluated (even if not re-painted).

Is there a way to avoid those re-evaluations on small changes?

I am asking because I saw a performance hit when I ran the app with [mrdoob's stats.js tool](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/).

I thought of using 'shouldComponentUpdate' but that means every time I add a sibling for **Evaluator** I need to tell it not to update when isImageFocused is updated.

I wish there was something such as "silentProps" which would enable me to pass props through the component tree to end leafs without causing a massive re-evaluations. Is there?

Comment: At some point I think it becomes pertinent to ask if there are any great advantages from storing a piece of state in the Redux store versus in the component. I generally delegate small UI related state to the state of the component because 1) simplicity (doesn't cloud the Redux store) and 2) Performance

Comment: How would one get those pieces of state to the component? What would be a good way to go around the redux propagation?

Comment: You can set up the default state during construction of the component, and then use ```setState``` to keep it up to date. You can access the state by ```this.state```. This automatically circumvents the Redux store, since it uses setState instead of dispatching an action.

Comment: True but it means the state is trapped inside the component. Do you use an event system to notify other parts of the app with this approach?

Comment: I only use the component state for data that is not required by any other parts of the app, but only used by the component itself, and _perhaps_ it's children (you can pass component state properties through children props). For your example, does anywhere else in the app need to know of the value ```isImageFocused```?

Comment: yes, different parts

Comment: And anyway I think reacts re-evauates components even on state change
http://files.parsetfss.com/c80e11bf-75e2-4fde-a341-518af5c53eb8/tfss-60f953e9-7adc-4784-89d6-40bbd555371a-Screen%20Shot%202016-07-28%20at%204.56.58%20PM.png so I am not sure what is the difference between using state and using props re-evaluation-wise.